# Joining tables to get all rows from left and all rows from right including unmatched rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to combine 2 tables - `IV00101` and `SOP30300`. `IV00101` contains all of our part numbers that are setup in the database, while `SOP30300` contains all of our line items sold. If there is a non-stock item that is sold (aka not in `IV00101`) it will be in `SOP30300` where I can retrieve it using `CSLSINDX =137`. What I need to join the tables by is part numbers, but I need all rows from `SOP30300` regardless of whether or not the part number is in `IV00101`

Here is my attempt at it - but I know it is missing some things because when I exclude the `IV00101` table, I get more rows returned (1575 w/o `IV00101` Join ; 1182 w/ Join)

```
(SELECT
        partTable.SOPNUMBE,
        partTable.LNITMSEQ,
        partTable.[Ship To Customer],
        partTable.UNITCOST,
        partTable.QUANTITY,
        partTable.CSLSINDX,
        cogsTable.ITEMNMBR,
        cogsTable.ITMSHNAM
        FROM
            (SELECT
                parts.ITEMNMBR,
                parts.SOPNUMBE,
                parts.LNITMSEQ,
                parts.ShipToName,
                parts.CNTCPRSN AS [Ship To Customer],
                parts.UNITCOST,
                parts.QUANTITY,
                parts.CSLSINDX
                FROM METRO.dbo.SOP30300 parts WHERE SOPNUMBE like 'I%' AND CSLSINDX = 137
            ) partTable

            LEFT JOIN
                (SELECT
                    cogs.ITEMNMBR,
                    cogs.ITMSHNAM
                    FROM METRO.dbo.IV00101 cogs WHERE IVCOGSIX = 137 AND ITMSHNAM <> 'TM' AND ITMSHNAM <> 'Rebate'
                )cogsTable
                ON cogsTable.ITEMNMBR = partTable.ITEMNMBR
    ) partNumbers
```

- Returns 1182 Rows

```
(SELECT
    partTable.SOPNUMBE,
    partTable.LNITMSEQ,
    partTable.[Ship To Customer],
    partTable.UNITCOST,
    partTable.QUANTITY,
    partTable.CSLSINDX,
    partTable.ITEMNMBR

    FROM
            (SELECT
                parts.ITEMNMBR,
                parts.SOPNUMBE,
                parts.LNITMSEQ,
                parts.ShipToName,
                parts.CNTCPRSN AS [Ship To Customer],
                parts.UNITCOST,
                parts.QUANTITY,
                parts.CSLSINDX
                FROM METRO.dbo.SOP30300 parts WHERE SOPNUMBE like 'I%' AND CSLSINDX = 137
            ) partTable
) partNumbers
```

-Returns 1575 rows

Would someone please be able to tell me how I am incorrectly joining the two tables?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join?rq=1

Comment: I would assume you get more rows because there are rows in `SOP30300` that have _multiple_ matches in `IV00101`.   aNull value in `cogsTable.ITEMNMBR` would tell you if there was a match or not.

Comment: Seems that you are looking for a CROSS JOIN between both Tables.

Comment: You seem to be massively overcomplicating this query. I do not see any point of using subqueries, this can be achieved by simple join between the 2 tables.

Comment: What are you joining on? Item number? @Shadow is right. There's no need for all of the subqueries. You should just have to select from the SOP30300 table and LEFT JOIN the parts table on some key.

Comment: @Shadow I definitely think I am over complicating this, I guess I've been staring at it for too long. Originally I was joining the tables the other way and excluding entries that weren't in `SOP30300`. I guess I should try this again...

Comment: This can't be the code that you are running you have an alias and then you don't use the alias in the where clause.  Please post the ACTUAL code that got these results.  (*I bet the problem will be quite clear then*)

Comment: @Hogan It may help, but it's about 150 lines. If you still want I can post it. Shadow's suggestion helped me out but the number of returned rows changes slightly depending on how I structure the query and never actually get as many rows as I did originally, so I will have to do some more testing to see why it leaves out certain things

Comment: @Adjit - don't bother... read my answer and you will understand (I hope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left join:

```
SELECT
  parts.SOPNUMBE,
  parts.LNITMSEQ,
  parts.CNTCPRSN AS [Ship To Customer],
  parts.UNITCOST,
  parts.QUANTITY,
  parts.CSLSINDX
  cogs.ITEMNMBR,
  cogs.ITMSHNAM
FROM METRO.dbo.SOP30300 parts 
LEFT JOIN METRO.dbo.IV00101 cogs ON cogs.ITEMNMBR = parts.ITEMNMBR AND cogs.IVCOGSIX = 137 AND cogs.ITMSHNAM <> 'TM' AND cogs.ITMSHNAM <> 'Rebate'
WHERE parts.SOPNUMBE like 'I%' AND parts.CSLSINDX = 137
```

Note, a number of the requirements on IV00101 have to be in the ON part of the join so they are a filter on the JOIN and not on whole query.  If you put those in the WHERE you make an inner join which would return less results.

The reason it would become an inner join is because you can't filter on NULL so when you would normally get a null for cogs columns you just exclude them -- this is the equivalent of an inner join.

Comment: did you intend to include the `ON` keyword?

Comment: I was trying to keep it from scrolling horizontally, and noticed you missed the `ON`

Comment: Thanks Hogan. It definitely clears things up. Appreciate the help and will test this a little more to understand better

Comment: @Adjit -- the way this works is one of the hardest parts of working with joins -- I've made this mistake myself often -- remember to put your join target filters after the `ON`

Comment: @Hogan so now why not put all of the `AND`s into the `WHERE`? or does the `WHERE` have to be the `FROM` table?

Comment: @Hogan, I wanted to read the conditions without scrolling horizontally and just happened to notice the typo, I thought it told you when there were edits pending, but maybe that's only for questions, not answers.  Didn't intend for you to lose your changes, but you always have the option to reject edits, so no content was lost.

Comment: @Adjit -- you can do it in the WHERE or in the JOIN.  Where you put the filter will change the results.

Comment: @hogan in what way would it change the results?

Comment: @Hogan thx, didn't know, thought I'd seen that before.  Like I said, just wanted to add LFs so didn't scroll horiz.

Comment: @adjit it would change it from a left join to an inner join.  Having it in the where would give fewer records.

Comment: @Beth -- As I said it is no problem -- people like you reviewing my answers is what makes SO great.